# Instance of a class only returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, instance

Fairly new to swift, and struggling with creating an instance of a class within another class. I'm firing a notification and then in my app delegate it responds by playing the music player and changing  label in my viewController, but when it tries to change the label app crashes with error "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". I can get round it by adding a '?' but why is it getting nil.

Code

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var musicPlayerManager: MusicPlayerManager = MusicPlayerManager()
var viewController: ViewController = ViewController()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {

        //show an alert window
        var playlistName: String = ""
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            playlistName = userInfo["soundName"] as! String
        }
        musicPlayerManager.playPlaylist(chosenPlaylist: playlistName)
        print(playlistName)
        viewController.currentPlaylist.text = "Playlist: \(playlistName)"

    }

}
```

I'm getting the playlistName printed in the console, and then it crashes with the last line suggesting that it's an issue with the instance of viewController, and my attempt to change the label in the view controller from the app delegate.

Comment: The default initializer `ViewController()` never returns the instance in the storyboard. You need the actual reference via segue or instantiation (depends on your design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlets are nil until vc loads also you need to load it from storyboard if it exists there

```
viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "id") as! ViewController 
viewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
viewController.currentPlaylist.text = "Playlist: \(playlistName)"
```

Comment: This has stopped the nil value, and when I do print(viewController.currentPlaylist.text) I get the desired value, but it doesn't actually change the value of the label like it does if it was being called from the ViewController class

Comment: It worked after I added the line self.window?.rootViewController = viewController. Details here http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/navigate-appdelegate-swift-different-viewcontroller/. Don't really understand why it works, but it does

Comment: the answer fixes your crash , the line you commented makes that vc the root and shows it that's why it's worked

Comment: But I've just noticed that I lose my navigation bar, do I have to make the navigation controller preceding the vc the root? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: embed the vc inside a navigation controller and then assign the nav as the root

Comment: let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController);
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController;
        viewController.currentPlaylist?.text = "Playlist: \(playlistName)";
        self.window?.rootViewController = nav;

It didn't work if I just set root to 'nav' but it did when I went to VC first then 'nav' as above. This feels like I'm doing it quite backward though!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use storyboard you can create your ViewController in this structure. But you need to add your Subview(currentPlaylist) into your view and also need to set it's frame

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let currentPlaylist = UILabel()

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        currentPlaylist.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(currentPlaylist)
    }
}
```